# Debug Sampler not showing Regular Expression Extractor Variables

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have issue with debug sampler not showing regular expression extractor in Jmeter. Kindly refer the tree below:

[image: Debug sampler 1]

Here is the information in my regular expression extractor:

[image: debug sampler info]

There's no regular expression variables shown in debug sampler output:
[image: reg expr var]

[image: parameter reg expr]

Can help to see what's the real issue here? FYI I'm scripting using webtours demo website & havent parameterize username and password yet coz i want to make sure my correlation works first. Thanks.

Comment: Try Template `$1$`

Comment: I've tried, still not working. Same output in the debug sampler. In the Response Data > Response Body also says "You've reached this page incorrectly (probably a bad user session value)."

Comment: so probably regex is wrong, try using CSS extractor

Comment: How to use it in this case? I've search about it and it seems more complicated than regex

Comment: Ok i already try using CSS Extractor, but still same, no output in debug sampler listener

Answer (score 0):

1. Without seeing the response it's hard to say what is wrong, most probably your Regular Expression Extractor fails somewhere somehow, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

   > **Template**
   > The template used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is: '$1$' to refer to group 1, '$2$' to refer to group 2, etc. $0$ refers to whatever the entire expression matches.

   so for sure you need to change `$1` to `$1$`
2. [Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would recommend consider using [CSS Selector Extractor instead](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/), the relevant configuration would be something like

   [image]
3. I don't think your PostProcessor placement is correct, it's a **Post** processor so according to the [JMeter test elements execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) it is executed **after** the sampler and you're trying to use the variable in the same request. So my expectation is that you need to move it under the "Homepage" sampler
4. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

Comment: 1. Already change to $1$, still no changes
2. I tried to use CSS Selector Extractor and display the result in Debug Sampler output, however no changes
3. Yes I already move it under Homepage sampler
4. Already add HTTP Cookie Manager - this was added automatically when I'm recording with Blazemeter plugins. Is there any additional configuration need to be done then?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter just now, kindly read the edited comments above

Comment: Any thoughts on the first comment?

Comment: Any thoughts on 1st point? Without seeing the response where this `userSession` is present we cannot help you efficiently